# Postscript (.ps) image does not import into .tex file or pdf

Tags: unix, gnuplot, postscript, ps

I am trying to:

1. Export a gnuplot .gpl file to a .ps
2. Get my .tex file to use the .ps file as an image
3. Convert that .tex file to a pdf

I created the following gnuplot .gpl file which exports 'a03e02.ps' as its output:

```
set terminal postscript portrait
set title "Dirac Delta-Function"
set xrange[-.01:.01]
set yrange[*:*]
set xlabel 'Independent Variable'
set ylabel 'Dependent Variable'
plot sin(2500*x)/(pi*x)
set output 'a03e02.ps'
```

The .ps file successfully appears after I run "gnuplot a03e02.gpl" in the command line. My .tex file that I want to read the .ps file read as such:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
$\delta_n(x)=\frac{sin(nx)}{{\pi}x}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{ixt}dt$
\end{equation}
\\
\begin{figure}
\centerline{
\includegraphics[width=8cm,angle=270]{a03e02.ps}
}
\caption{This is the Dirac $\delta$-function graphed between $x=\pm.01$ for $n=2500$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It is quite simple and should be working fine, but when I try either of the following to my .tex file (dirac.tex) I get a pdf that has no image from the .ps file:

```
latex2e dirac.tex
dvipdf dirac.dvi
```

or

```
pdflatex dirac.tex
```

When I use the latex2e > dvipdf method, I even get a latex file that displays my entries out of order!

You can take a look at the output here to see what I am talking about:

http://www.physics.utah.edu/~u0459335/dirac.pdf

Thank you in advance for any direction, you guys are always helpful. :)

Comment: This may be too obvious, but did you try `dvips` and then `ps2pdf` as separate steps?

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate on how dvips would help me (I thought it was for converting dvi to ps which is the opposite of the process here, but I could be wrong), but per your advice I tried using ps2pdf to change a03e02.ps to a03e02.pdf and changing the .tex file to read .pdf as the graphics output but it comes up blank.

I am starting to think that it is just my school machines. I am using SSH to go into them and every week they seem to be missing plugins, programs, etc. Last week we had a problem because the systems administrator let the server fill up and we got Disk Quota errors. Fun :(

Comment: I've added more explanation as an answer. For Disk Quota problems, make sure you delete any `*.core` files that might have been created by crashed programs. HTH. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem is, that you must `set output` before plotting!

```
set terminal postscript ps
set output 'a03e02.ps'
plot sin(2500*x)/(pi*x)
```

I tested with `dvipdf`, and it worked for me (TeXLive 2013), but personally I always use the `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf` chain.

Some comments to the LaTeX-document:

- You must include the `graphicx` package
- You cannot use `$` inside the `equation`-environment
- `figure` is a floating environment, no need to place a `\\` before it (BTW: This is also wrong for adding a new paragraph, this is done by an empty line or a `\par`).
- An opened bracket `{` with a newline is prone for extra spacings.
- Why do you rotate the image by `270`?
- I wouldn't set the `width` in the LaTeX-document but rather in the `gnuplot` script, so that you do not have different scalings for different images. Although you have vector images, the linewidth will change and the font size also.
- You shouldn't set the image extension in the `\includegraphics` argument.
- Use `\sin` instead of `sin`.

Here is how I would do it:

```
set terminal postscript eps size 8cm,6cm
set title "Dirac Delta-Function"
set xrange[-.01:.01]
set xlabel 'Independent Variable'
set ylabel 'Dependent Variable'
set samples 1000
set output 'a03e02.eps'
plot sin(2500*x)/(pi*x)
```

The LaTeX-document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\delta_n(x)=\frac{\sin(nx)}{{\pi}x}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{ixt}dt
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{a03e02}
\caption{This is the Dirac $\delta$-function graphed between $x=\pm.01$ for $n=2500$.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This gives (using `latex -> dvipdf`):

[image]

You could also use the `epslatex` terminal to get the same fonts and enhanced math in you `gnuplot` image.

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much for also explaining the positioning of set output and the usepackage{graphicx} line in the LaTeX document.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: The following may be of historical interest only, or useful only on older installations! It appears that recent versions dvipdf will invoke gs to convert the graphics to pdf automatically.*

When you include a postscript graphic in your document, you will also need to include a postscript processor in the chain. Instead of

```
latex2e dirac.tex
dvipdf dirac.dvi
```

try

```
latex2e dirac.tex
dvips dirac.dvi
ps2pdf dirac.ps
```

`dvipdf` can convert the "dvi" (TeX's native output format) directly into pdf, but it cannot process the postscript program. `dvips` works just the same, but it outputs postscript, and your included graphic will be included in the output. Then, `ps2pdf` can convert the whole thing to pdf.

`dvipdf` is a more recent program that skips the postscript step. But if you need to insert postscript, it needs to be processed by a postscript interpreter.

Comment: I get less errors this time, but document still appears pretty much the same. You can view the output here still:

http://www.physics.utah.edu/~u0459335/dirac.pdf

That is a really good explanation about the need for dvips, though! :)

Comment: I found one document that suggests converting to EPS (encapsulated postscript) first: http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3907319 and another document that suggests adding `\usepackage{graphicx}` to the preamble: http://www.math.mun.ca/~edgar/includeps.html . Latex is a little out of my expertise. :(